# How to scroll clicked row of Android GridLayoutManager to top of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am using a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager, I need to scroll the clicked view to the top of the RecyclerView, but using the built in `mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);` method does nothing, even when using a handler to delay the scroll behaviour, has anyone been able to make  this work?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the layout manager's scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset) method. 
This worked for me:

```
layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 0);
```

The offset parameter is the distance (in pixels) between the start edge of the item view and start edge of the RecyclerView.

Comment: Doesnt seem like this is available with the GridLayoutManager, looks like only the LinearLayoutManager does this :/

Comment: I use a GridLayoutManager and it works for me. recyclerview-v7:24.2.1.